# FindAll in a list of custom objects

Tags: c#, list, mscorlib

Well, I got an object called Mamamia and inside of it has some string properties. I created a list of this object and populated it with 150 items.

I'm trying to use List.FindAll but I reaaally don't know how to do it. I've tried this way:

```
produto = products.FindAll(delegate(Mamamia cv) {return cv.LocalPackage.Remove(1,21) == cmbPackage.SelectedValue};
```

I don't know why the delegate is there, I just tried to copy from some other code on the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate is there to see whether the value that you're testing is what you're looking for. The call to `Remove` looks worryingly like it's mutating the value though - that's rarely a good thing when you're looking through the list. I guess if it's a string then it's not too bad, although it may not be what you're after...

What are the types involved, and what are you looking for? Oh, and are you using C# 3 and/or .NET 3.5? That would make it easier (even C# 3 against .NET 2.0 means you could use a lambda expression instead of an anonymous method).

What's happening when you run the code at the moment? If it's just not finding anything, it *may* just be because you're testing for reference equality (if `SelectedValue` returns `object`).

Try this:

```
produto = products.FindAll(delegate(Mamamia cv) {
    return cv.LocalPackage.Remove(1,21).Equals(cmbPackage.SelectedValue);
});
```

EDIT:

It sounds like you only want a single value, and if you're using .NET 3.5 it would be more idiomatic to use LINQ in the first place. I would use:

```
string selectedText = (string) cmbPackage.SelectedValue;
Mamamia item = products.FirstOrDefault
                  (cv => cv.LocalPackage.Remove(1,21) == selectedText);
if (item != null)
{
    // Found it; otherwise item will be null
}
```

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5 and when I run the code, I'm getting the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FindMSIProducts.Mamamia>' to 'FindMSIProducts.Mamamia

I'm looking for a propertie inside a list of Mamamia objects

Comment: @Felipe: Is your `produto` variable of type `List<Mamamia>` or just `Mamamia` itself? If you just want to return a single item then use the `Find` method rather than `FindAll`. If you're expecting to return multiple items then change the type of `produto` to `List<Mamamia>`.

Comment: produto is a Mamamia object and products is a List<Mamamia> this list can have duplicated items and I want to return all of them

Comment: How do you expect to return all of them if produto isn't a collection?